# windchill 10.2: custom action does not appear in product structure explorer

Tags: ptc-windchill

I am unable to view an custom action in the pub when I right click on an part. Ptc guide does not provide any step by step procedure to implement this function.

Action name ="psbaction1" 
Class name = grid.reject

Is there s specific format within which it has to be specified?

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Have you added your entries properly in appropriate `*-actions.xml` and             `*-actionmodels.xml` ? Windchill customization guide have enough information about actions framework in gui. Show us your entry to get more help on this.

Comment: Hi Vignesh, I am unable to upload an image due to system restriction :(. I would like to add another action within the context menu when I right click on the part in the structure tab.

Answer (score 0):

please find the below configurations and help in creating a CustomAction Class. When clicked the newly added custom action the CustomAction class should execute (work should be done in background)

**custom-actionModels.xml**:

```
   <model name="psbRelatedPartsTreeContextMenu">
    ..
                <action name="psbaction1" type="psb"/>

   </model>
```

**custom-actions.xml** :

```
  <listofactions>
    <objecttype name="psb" resourceBundle="ext.custom.psb.resource.psbCustomActionsRB">
        <action name="psbaction1">
         <command class="sample.CustomAction"/>
      </action>
    </objecttype>
</listofactions>
```

**psbCustomActionsRB.rbinfo**:

```
psb.psbaction1.description.value=psbaction1
psb.psbaction1.tooltip.value=psbaction1
psb.psbaction1.title.value=psbaction1
psb.psbaction1.icon.value=stop.gif
psb.psbaction1.moreurlinfo.value=height=300,width=500
```

Comment: Hi,I did add these details in the respective XML files but I still don't see the action in the "psbRelatedPartsTreeContextMenu" but the action appears when I use the snippet that is provided by the PTC customization document. <command class="com.ptc.cat.ui.client.action.LaunchURLAction"
method="execute" url="/ptc1/psb/customAction" windowType="popup"/> Am I doing missing something?